# Command changed for all documents

Tags: math-mode, texmaker

I'm running into an issue that has left me a little perplexed. For reference, I'm using Texmaker 5.0.4.

I wanted to define a command for `\mathcal{l}`, so I tried doing

```
\newcommand{\l}{\mathcal{l}}
```

That gave me an error message saying `\l` was already defined, so instead I tried

```
\renewcommand{\l}{\mathcal{l}}
```

But then, in the pdf whenever I wrote `\l` I got the arrow `\updownarrow` instead of what I wanted. Not only that, what concerns me more is that whenever I write `\mathcal{l}` I get this arrow instead, even when I do it in other documents. 
I created this new document to try to fix it in a simpler setting but was unable to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{l}$

\end{document}
```

There's no commands being renewed, but the output from that is an `\updownarrow` arrow. So it has to be an issue with Texmaker. Does anyone have any idea why this happened and how it can be fixed? Thanks!

Comment: There is no lowercase letter available for `\mathcal`, only uppercase. What you get from `\mathcal{<lowercase letter>}` is essentially random. Do you perhaps mean what you get with `\ell`? Another advice: *never* do `\renewcommand` on commands you don't know about.

Comment: @egreg Ok I feel dumb now, thanks! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for lowercase letters in `\mathcal` (some fonts have it, in particular the STIX fonts).

If you do `\mathcal{<lowercase letter>}` you get a random symbol (not really random, actually, but quite unpredictable if you don't know how the command works internally).

What you want seems already provided by `\ell`.

Be careful! Never do `\renewcommand` on something you don't know about, particularly commands with short names. In the particular case, you'd get in trouble if your bibliography refers to some Polish author, for instance Dybała.